# Prove the irrationality of $e=\exp(1)$ with $\exp $ defined as solution of ODE

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers

I am writing math lessons as I will teach soon on my freetime. 
In my course, 
I defined $\exp(x)$ as the solution to the O.D.E : 
 $$f'(x)=f(x),\qquad f(0)=1$$
Is there a way to prove, maybe by contradiction, that $e$ is irrational without using series?

Comment: You can always prove that the solution is $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, and then prove $f(1)$ is irrational. You usually prove irrationality of $e$ by an infinite sum, so it's the most straight up approach.

Comment: Seems to me you could just use the normal proof. Just avoid defining $e$ as a sum and use Taylor's theorem centered at $0$ extrapolated to $1$ directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is; I think you'll have to prove $e=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{k!}$ first. However, there's an easy way to do that using the ODE. We make repeated use of $f(1)=1+\int_0^1 f(t) dt$: $$f(1)=1+\int_0^1 (1+\int_0^t f(t') dt')dt+\cdots$$So $$f(1)=1+\int_0^1 dt+\int_0^1 dt\int_0^t dt' t'+\cdots=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{k!}.$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit the last line ? I don't see where the factorial comes from. Thanks

Comment: @T.D. Here's the simplest way to understand it. The $k$th term after the $1$ is a $k$-tuple integral with ordered integration variables $\in [0,\,1]$, so a random point in the unit hypercube has a $1/k!$ probability of "counting". So instead of the integrand, which is equal to the constant $1$, integrating to the hypercube's volume $1$, it's only $1/k!$.